# Move torrent in folders fixing moving inside folders

Tags: batch-file

I use 2 scripts to reordening by year torrent files inside folders but each of these scripts are incomplete because I must use both to move them.

For example

*1st scripts*

```
    @Echo Off
For %%a In (*19???.torrent *20???.torrent) Do Call :Sub "%%~a"
Exit/B
:Sub
Set "mfn=%~n1"
Set "lfc=%mfn:~-5%
Set "lfc=%lfc:(= %"
Set "lfc=%lfc:)= %"
Set "lfc=%lfc: =%"
If Not Exist "%lfc%\" MD %lfc%
Move %1 %lfc%
```

**DON'T MOVE** files like (files extension is .torrent)

```
Animali Pazzi (1939) Toto
Anno 2000 La Corsa Della Morte
American History X 1998 1080p ENG
Devil 2010_001
```

*2nd script*

```
@Echo Off
For /F "Tokens=*" %%a In (
    'Dir/B/A-D *.torrent^|Findstr/R "\<19[0-9][0-9]\> \<20[0-1][0-9]\>"') Do (
    For %%b In (%%~na) Do Call :Sub "%%a" "%%b")
Pause
Exit/B
:Sub
Set "mfn=%~2"
Set "mfn=%mfn:(=%"
If %mfn:)=% GEq 1900 (If %mfn:)=% Lss 2017 (If Not Exist "%mfn:)=%\" MD %mfn:)=%
        Move %1 %mfn:)=%))
```

but **DON'T MOVE** files like

```
Alla 39 Eclisse - The Awakening 1980_001
Predators 2010_002
Sono il Numero Quattro.2011_001
Abbronzatissimi.1991.avi
Continuavano a chiamarlo trinita1971 x264
32.Dicembre.1988.avi
```

I want a FUSION of both script that FIXING this moving problem.

Comment: You can try with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39345515/2861476).

Comment: That solution create only folders correcly not move files. I try to add my code but something is wrong

Comment: It is indicated in the answer. The `move` command is prefixed with an `echo` for debugging purposes. Remove the `echo` leaving the `move` if the output to console is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a different scripting method, such as powershell:

```
$ToFolder = "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\to"
$FromFolder = "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\From"

#Create the sample folder on your desktop
#This line can be commented out if your ToFolder exists
New-Item $ToFolder -ItemType directory -Force

GCI -Path $FromFolder *.torrent | % {
    if ($_.Name -match "(19|20)\d{2}") {

        #Check to see if year folder already exists at the destination
        #If not then create a folder based on this year
        if (!(Test-Path "$ToFolder\$($Matches[0])")) {
            New-Item -Path "$ToFolder\$($Matches[0])" -ItemType directory
        }

        #Transfer the matching file to its new folder
        #Can be changed to Move-Item if happy with the results
        Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination "$ToFolder\$($Matches[0])" -Force
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution is great. I replace `Copy-Item` with `Move-Item`